# updating the scope within a directive from a controller when the directive is not part of ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

My problem is quite specific so I haven't been able to find an answer for this particular scenario anywhere, I did manage to get the functionality I require but would like to know if there is a better way of doing it. I will start by explaining the problem.

In index.html I have the following:

```
<html>
 ...
 <lumx-navbar></lumx-navbar>
 <div class="wrap">
    <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
 ...
</html>
```

lumxnavbar is a directive for the navigation bar of the application

**nav.js**

```
 module.exports = function(appModule) {
    appModule.directive('lumxNavbar', function(UserFactory, $window, $rootScope) {
        return {
            template: require('./nav.html'),
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.nav = require('../../static-data/nav.json');
                $scope.user = $rootScope.user;
                $scope.logout = function() {
                    UserFactory.logout();
                    $scope.user = '';
                    $window.location.href = '/#/login';
                };

            }
        };
    });
};
```

**nav.html**

```
<header>
 ...
 <span ng-show="user" class="main-nav--version">Logged in as: {{user}}</span>
 ...
</header>
```

So the application starts with a login page at which point there is no user variable available anywhere. Once the user logs in there will be a user returned from a service.

my routes look like this (I am using angular-ui-router)

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('anon', {
            abstact: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            data: {
                access: false
            }
        })
        .state('anon.login', {
            url: '/login',
            template: require('../views/login.html'),
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        });
    $stateProvider
        .state('user', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            data: {
                access: true
            }
        })
        .state('user.home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: require('../views/home.html'),
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
    ...
```

so the idea is that once the user logs in the navbar will change from

[image]

to this:

[image]

the only way I have found to accomplish this reliably is to do the following

**instantiate a variable in $rootScope**

```
appModule.run(function($rootScope, $location, UserFactory, $state) {
    $rootScope.user = UserFactory.getUser();
...
```

**then set the same variable from the login controller**

```
...
        $scope.login = function (username, password) {
            UserFactory.login(username, password).then(function success(response) {
                $rootScope.user = response.data.user.username;
                $state.go('user.home');
            }, handleError);
        };
...
```

so this will update the navbar because of this line in the directive `$scope.user = $rootScope.user;` but my question is whether there is a better way of doing this without using `$rootScope` or would this be a suitable use for it?

Any input would be appreciated...:)